# Flutter How to get the value of a Provider out

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have this Provider in my code. its suppose to return list

```
class ServingProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Serving> servings = [];

  getServings() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('servings')
        .getDocuments()
        .then((value) => value.documents)
        .then((value) =>
            value.map((serving) => Serving.fromJson(serving.data)).toList())
        .then((value) => servings.addAll(value))
        .then((value) => notifyListeners());
    print(servings);
  }

  // List<Serving> get servings => servings;
}
```

I want to get the value here but I'm getting null for some reason.

```
class KMultiScrollWheel extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String value;
  final BuildContext passedContext;
  final String dialogTitle;

  KMultiScrollWheel({
    @required this.title,
    this.value,
    @required this.passedContext,
    this.dialogTitle,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final servings = Provider.of<ServingProvider>(context).servings;
    print(servings)
```

This is the wrapper of my class.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (_) => ServingProvider(),
                  child: KMultiScrollWheel(
                    title: 'Serving Size',
                    passedContext: context,
                    dialogTitle: 'Select Serving',
                  ),
                ),
```

I'm coming from react and I'm completely lost for something that should be rather simple. thanks in advance.

One last question whats the point of using get method when I can access the servings already declared at the top.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using realtime database, use `StreamProvider` instead of `ChangeNotifierProvider` , this [medium article](https://medium.com/codechai/flutter-provider-and-streams-33b401ebe28c) can help you out

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this and can't comment since I am not sure if this will work, but I don't see you calling the getServings method, so maybe your list isn't filled yet?

You could try something like this:

```
final servingsProvider = Provider.of<ServingProvider>(context);
(await) servingsProvider.getServings(); //and make getServings() async since it connects to Firebase
print(servingsProvider.servings);
```

Of course you should handle this in a future or streambuilder, to render it.

Answer (score 0):

I think `getServings` is a Future function, so you must handle the case when **servings is null**. You can simply add getServings in the constructor of `ServingProvider`:

```
class ServingProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ServingProvider(){
    // call getServings in constructor, notify listener when servings update
    getServings();
  }
  ...
```

and handle *null case of servings* in `KMultiScrollWheel build` by your own.

The other ways are **FutureProvider** (set initialData when data is not ready) or **StreamProvider**.